When using Spring Boot with CXF, can Spring Security / actuator be configured if cxf.path is set to /?
For "reasons" out of my control the current configuration has cxf.path=/. I am trying to add Spring Actuator and Spring Security and I am unable to get the two working as long as the path stays '/'. Everything that does not require authentication works ok, but for everything else I get either 404 or "No service was found".
I currently have:

host/soap1
host/api/rest1

and I am trying to add

host/actuator

application.properties
cxf.path=/
cxf.jaxrs.server.address=/api
cxf.jaxrs.component-scan=true

As soon as I remove cxf.path or change it to something other than /, everything starts working.  That however changes the paths for /soap1 and /soap2, which I am trying to avoid.
Minimum setup to replicate (borrowing code from JAX-WS Spring Boot demo)
Gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws:4.0.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
}

Configuration:
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Bus bus;

    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, new HelloPortImpl(), null, null, null);
        endpoint.publish("/Hello");
        return endpoint;
    }
}

application.properties
cxf.path=/
spring.application.name=demo

log
2024-10-10T10:51:25.569-05:00 INFO 33776 --- [demo] [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.8.1 with PID 33776 (C:\Temp\test-source\demo\bin\main started by user in C:\Temp\test-source\demo)
2024-10-10T10:51:25.572-05:00 INFO 33776 --- [demo] [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-10-10T10:51:26.317-05:00 WARN 33776 --- [demo] [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). The currently created BeanPostProcessor [annotationActionEndpointMapping] is declared through a non-static factory method on that class; consider declaring it as static instead.
2024-10-10T10:51:26.338-05:00 INFO 33776 --- [demo] [           main] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2024-10-10T10:51:26.499-05:00 INFO 33776 --- [demo] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-10-10T10:51:26.509-05:00 INFO 33776 --- [demo] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-10-10T10:51:26.510-05:00 INFO 33776 --- [demo] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.30]
2024-10-10T10:51:26.559-05:00 INFO 33776 --- [demo] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-10-10T10:51:26.559-05:00 INFO 33776 --- [demo] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 955 ms
2024-10-10T10:51:26.812-05:00 INFO 33776 --- [demo] [           main] o.a.c.w.s.f.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean : Creating Service {http://demo.example.com/}HelloService from class com.example.demo.Hello
2024-10-10T10:51:27.068-05:00 INFO 33776 --- [demo] [           main] org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl       : Setting the server's publish address to be /Hello
2024-10-10T10:51:27.377-05:00 INFO 33776 --- [demo] [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint beneath base path '/actuator'
2024-10-10T10:51:27.419-05:00 INFO 33776 --- [demo] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'
2024-10-10T10:51:27.428-05:00 INFO 33776 --- [demo] [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 2.126 seconds (process running for 3.066)
2024-10-10T10:51:34.835-05:00 WARN 33776 --- [demo] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.t.servlet.ServletController        : Can't find the request for http://localhost:8080/actuator's Observer 

